# Android Custom list view with radio group issue

Tags: android, radio-button, android-arrayadapter, radio-group, custom-lists

I want to make a custom list of radio groups, that should has a text view and a radio group in each item and each radio group contains radio buttons, i could do it but there's a problem....,  the radio buttons are repeated more than it should be in each item and i can select more than one radio button in a radio group which is wrong,

here's what i've done:

PollsQuestionsAdapter

```
public class PollsQuestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
List<PollQuestion> pollQuestionList;

public PollsQuestionsAdapter(Context context, List<PollQuestion> pollQuestionList) {
    super(context, R.layout.polls_questions_list_item, pollQuestionList);

    this.context = context;
    this.pollQuestionList = pollQuestionList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pollQuestionList.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.polls_questions_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    RadioGroup rgAnswer;
    TextView tvQuestion;
    tvQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.polls_questions_list_item_question_name);
    rgAnswer = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.polls_questions_list_item_answer);

    String questionName;
    List<PollAnswer> answerList;

    if (Language.lang.equals("EN") || Language.lang.equals("En") || Language.lang.equals("en"))
        questionName = pollQuestionList.get(position).getQuestionTextEN();
    else
        questionName = pollQuestionList.get(position).getQuestionTextAR();

    answerList = pollQuestionList.get(position).getAnswersList();

    rgAnswer.setTag(pollQuestionList.get(position).getQuestionId()); // to use it when you get the value of question id

    for (int i = 0; i < answerList.size(); i++) {

        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
        if (Language.lang.equals("EN") || Language.lang.equals("En") || Language.lang.equals("en"))
            radioButton.setText(answerList.get(i).getAnswerTextEN());
        else
            radioButton.setText(answerList.get(i).getAnswerTextAR());

        radioButton.setId(answerList.get(position).getAnswerId()); // to use it when you get the value of the answer id
        rgAnswer.addView(radioButton);
    }
    tvQuestion.setText(questionName);

    return convertView;
   }  
 }
```

polls_questions_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1E5BAC"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/polls_questions_list_item_question_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/polls_questions_list_item_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's how i called the adapter in my activity:

```
 List<PollQuestion> pollQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<PollAnswer> pollAnswerList = new ArrayList<>();

 pollAnswerList.add(new PollAnswer(1, "Yes", "نعم"));
 pollAnswerList.add(new PollAnswer(2, "No", "لا"));

 pollQuestionList.add(new PollQuestion("مواعيد المحاضرات بها تعارض", "Schedule has conflict", 1, pollAnswerList));

  pollAnswerList = new ArrayList<>();
  pollAnswerList.add(new PollAnswer(3, "High", "مرتفعة"));
  pollAnswerList.add(new PollAnswer(4, "Medium", "متوسطة"));
  pollAnswerList.add(new PollAnswer(5, "Low", "منخفضة"));

 pollQuestionList.add(new PollQuestion("مواعيد المحاضرات موزعة بالتساوى خلال الاسبوع", "The lectures schedule is balanced during week",2, pollAnswerList));

 PollsQuestionsAdapter adapter = new PollsQuestionsAdapter(PollsQuestionsActivity.this, pollQuestionList);

 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is the result :

[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVTqG.png)

[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD2yk.png)

the first item should contain:
Yes and No only

the second item should contain:
High, Medium and Low only

and the radio buttons in each radio group should should be selected together, only one button is pressed and the others are disabled which doesn't happen in the items here.

so, could any one tell me what did i do wrong ?

Thanks in advance.